# Form submitting to wrong function when changing class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure there's a simple explanation for this but I haven't been able to find the right words to use when searching for answers.

When users fill out the form .InvoiceForm it submits via Ajax. After it's submitted remove the .InvoiceForm class and add .UpdateInvoice. When a user submits a .UpdateInvoice form it explains that they are about to make a change and they have to click to say "Yes I want this to be updated".

The issue is that unless I refresh the page so that the form is loaded with the .UpdateInvoice form, I don't get the confirmation which means it's still submitting as a .InvoiceForm form. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Edit to show code:

Code that runs if there's no record

```
$('.InvoiceForm').submit(function(e) {

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() { 
                $(".validation-errors").hide().empty(); 
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).removeClass('InvoiceForm');
                $(this).addClass('UpdateInvoice');
                $(this).find('.btn').val('Update');
                $(this).find('.id').val(data.invoice_id);
                $(this).find('.btn').removeClass('btn-default');
                $(this).find('.btn').addClass('btn-danger');
                $(this).find('.AddRow').removeClass('hide');
                $(this).find('.invoiceDetails').html(data.returnedData);
                $(this).parent().next().find('.grade').focus();

            }
        });
        return false;
};
```

Code that runs if there is a record being updated

```
$('.UpdateInvoice').submit(function(){

        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to make this update?");
        if (r == true) {
            $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() { 
                $(".validation-errors").hide().empty(); 
            },
            success: function(data) {

                alert('This row has been updated');
                $(this).find('.total').html(data);   
            }
        });
        } else {

        }
       return false;
   });
```

The function for .UpdateInvoice doesn't run unless I refresh the page.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to provide a code example of what you have been trying to do.

Comment: It sounds like there is JavaScript that runs when the page loads to set up the confirmation. But it can't set up the confirmation if the UpdateInvoice form isn't there when the page loads. You need that code to execute after the UpdateInvoice form is added to the page. If you show your code someone can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You bind a click event on '.UpdateInvoce' before it even being created, hence it'll not work. I think you need to use .live() in order to make it works. See document here: [jQuery's live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

HTML:

```
<button id="click_me" class="new">Click Me</button>
<div class="result" />
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
    $('.new').click(function (e) {
        $('.result').text("Im new !");
        $(this).removeClass("new");
        $(this).addClass("update");

        // Bind UpdateInvoice's click event on the fly
        $('.update').live(bindUpdate());
    });

    function bindUpdate() {
        $('.update').click(function (e) {
            $('.result').text("Update me !");
        });
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle's demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2gankv79/)

Comment: Does on() do the same thing as live()? It says live() has been depreciated.